# How to make constructor with my input?

Tags: c++

I'm stuck with a problem. Let's suppose I have a class `BigInteger` with the following constructor:

```
BigInteger(string s) {...}
```

And I want to do the following:

```
string s;
cin >> s;
BigInteger a(s);
```

Unfortunately, there's an issue, because I guess that would be valid if I write this:

```
string s = "12312123123";
BigInteger a(s);
```

Is it possible to define a constructor with input from keyboard?

Comment: Off-topic:  You should be passing the string as `const std::string& s`.  No need to copy the string to the function when you can refer to the existing one.

Comment: What does "I've catched a fault" mean?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley sorry for my English. I meant that my .cpp file doesn't compile.

Comment: include the error in this case please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use `std::istream`:

```
BigInteger(std::istream& input);
```

This constructor allows you to create a `BigInteger` from a file as well.

To use:

```
BigInteger bi(std::cin);
```

You may want to resolve your issue with `std::string` first.

Comment: So this constructor allows me for example this : writing some string from keyboard and make it BigInt?

Comment: The `std::cin` is derived from `std::istream`, so you can pass `std::cin` to any function that takes an `std::istream` parameter.